# Service or solution to integrate video/audio

Tags: audio, video, communication, voip

Is there a service or solution to integrate video/audio communications within your userbase on site or within application ?

Something like google hangouts, but users must have avatars and nicknames that is getting out of my database.

Answer (score 0):

There are some frameworks that may give you what you want.

Twilio provides tools to allow you build combinations into your apps - they explain it pretty well on the site.
http://www.twilio.com

Ericsson has also just open sourced their Web RTC browser:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/2691212/ericsson-releases-webrtc-browser-and-framework-as-open-source.html

Other examples include:

- https://www.plivo.com/web-sdk/
- http://www.webrtc.org/home

Essentially for the web application world, Web RTC is the technology you are most likely looking for and you will probably have to take a look at some of the more popular offering built around this to see which you like best and which best meets your needs.

If you want to build your own from the basic building blocks then Web RTC is a W3C standard based technology so you can find out about it here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC
- http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/